# Django Rest Framework: use create with primary key in URL

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I can't apply the `@action` decorator to `create` function within a standard `views.Viewset` subclass.

```
@action(detail=True) # This fails.
def create(self, request, pk=None):
    return Response(etc...)
```

On other methods, adding that decorator allows me to create URLs easily with `<pk>` within the URL. For example, I can send a `POST` request to `http://main_url.com/do_something_to_user_with_id/7/`, with `do_something_to_user_with_id` being some random function within the viewset and `7` being the user id/primary key.

Is there any way I can do this with `create`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewSet` provides following six actions - `list, create, retrieve, update, partial_update and destroy` - [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions)

So you don't need an `action` decorator to implement a route for the `create` method as its a default route for `post` calls as mentioned [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewsets) -

> A ViewSet class is simply a type of class-based View, that does not
> provide any method handlers such as .get() or .post(), and instead
> provides actions such as .list() and .create().

So if you have any method other than the six method names listed above that you want to be routable, then you can use the `@action` decorator. -[here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)

> If you have ad-hoc methods that should be routable, you can mark them
> as such with the @action decorator. Like regular actions, extra
> actions may be intended for either a single object, or an entire
> collection. To indicate this, set the detail argument to True or
> False.

Answer (score 0):

if you know about django-restframework then you can do something like

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view


@api_view(['GET'])
def create(self, request, pk=None):
    return Response(etc...)
```